# Does the half price star effect get used up if you refuse a star?

Tags: mario-party-superstars

Let's stay I land on a Lucky Space and roll "The cost of your next star is cut in half". If I pass a Star Space and say no to buying a star, will the star still be half price the next time I pass a Star Space?